# Morris Chart with dynamic data from C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, morris.js

I am trying to build a Morris graph in an ASP.NET web app, where the data that the graph is being populated with is coming from an ajax post to a C# method.

The return data is:

```
[{"process":"W3WP","xKey":"2018-8-1 7:00","yKey":"60"},
{"process":"Proc","xKey":"2018-8-1 7:00","yKey":"35"},
{"process":"W3WP","xKey":"2018-8-1 7:30","yKey":"75"},
{"process":"Proc","xKey":"2018-8-1 7:30","yKey":"30"},
{"process":"W3WP","xKey":"2018-8-1 8:00","yKey":"70"},
{"process":"Proc","xKey":"2018-8-1 8:00","yKey":"39"},
{"process":"W3WP","xKey":"2018-8-1 8:30","yKey":"71"},
{"process":"Proc","xKey":"2018-8-1 8:30","yKey":"30"}]
```

Basically, **I want a graph that shows CPU usage for a list (dynamic) of processes. Each process should be represented by a line.**
When I build the graph with the following JavaScript, the graph is not displaying correctly:

```
var procChart = new Morris.Line({
    element: 'chartProcesses',
    data: $.parseJSON(ProcGraph()),
    xkey: ['xKey'],
    ykeys: ['yKey'],
    labels: ['process'],
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true
});
```

The JSON post is as follows:

```
function ProcGraph() {
    var data = "";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Servers.aspx/GetGraphData',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {},
        success: function (result) {                                            
            data = result.d;
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });

    return data;
}
```

And finally, the C# class:

```
public class GraphChartData
{
    public string process { get; set; }
    public string xKey { get; set; }
    public string yKey { get; set; }

    public GraphChartData(string process, string _xKey, string _yKey)
    {
        this.process = process;
        this.xKey = _xKey;
        this.yKey = _yKey;
    }

    public GraphChartData()
    {
    }
}
```

Graph results as follows:
[Morris Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03OCv.png)

Comment: `not displaying correctly`: can you show it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a `WebMethod` that simulates dynamic data:

It generates a random number of lines and processes (between 2 and 5), then returns an object containing the labels, the yKeys and the data needed for the Morris Line graph.

```
[WebMethod]
public static object GetGraphData()
{
    Random random = new Random();

    List<Dictionary<string, object>> processes = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    List<string> labels = new List<string>();
    List<string> yKeys = new List<string>();
    bool labelsDone = false;

    int nbLines = random.Next(2, 5);
    int nbProcesses = random.Next(2, 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < nbLines; i++)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> processLine = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        string time = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(i).ToString();

        processLine.Add("datetime", time);

        for (int j = 0; j < nbProcesses; j++)
        {
            processLine.Add($"processName{j + 1}", random.Next(100));

            if (!labelsDone)
            {
                labels.Add($"Process Name{j + 1}");
                yKeys.Add($"processName{j + 1}");
            }
        }

        labelsDone = true;

        processes.Add(processLine);
    }

    return new
    {
        labels = labels,
        ykeys = yKeys,
        processes = processes
    };
}
```

JavaScript code used to get data from the `WebMethod` `GetGraphData`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ProcGraph();
});

function ProcGraph() {
    var data = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Servers.aspx/GetGraphData',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {},
        success: function (result) {
            data = result.d;
           SetMorris(data)
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });

    return data;
}

function SetMorris(data) {
    var procChart = new Morris.Line({
        element: 'chartProcesses',
        data: data.processes,
        xkey: ['datetime'],
        ykeys: data.ykeys,
        labels: data.labels,
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true,
        parseTime: false
    });
}
```

Please try the following snippet using data generated from the `WebMethod`:

```js
var data =
[
    { "datetime": "14/08/2018 14:41:28", "processName1": 2, "processName2": 50 },
    { "datetime": "14/08/2018 14:42:28", "processName1": 20, "processName2": 34 },
    { "datetime": "14/08/2018 14:43:28", "processName1": 17, "processName2": 81 },
    { "datetime": "14/08/2018 14:44:28", "processName1": 86, "processName2": 67 }
]

var procChart = new Morris.Line({
    element: 'chartProcesses',
    data : data,
    xkey: ['datetime'],
    ykeys: ['processName1', 'processName2'],
    labels: ['ProcessName1', "Process Name1"],
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true,
    parseTime: false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="chartProcesses"></div>
```

Make sure to set the `parseTime` attribute to `false`:

```
parseTime: false
```

Comment: Your solution is with static data. I need to be able to do this dynamically. W3WP and Proc might not always be the processes in the list...

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I tried using an ExpandoObject, but no luck - this works though!